# Can't Install Software From Windows Store

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store

I've got a new ASUS T100 with the newest BIOS installed and the latest windows updates installed.  My problem is that, no matter what I try to do, I cannot install anything from the Windows Store.

I have a connection to the internet.  I'm able to download and install things from the 'Desktop' - but any game or application I find through the store hangs on 'Downloading'.  I've tried several different programs and I've tried a different user with a different Microsoft account.....but it doesn't seem to matter what I do.

Can anyone please help me get this resolved?

There is no error message, it just hangs forever.

EDIT:  On additional attempts it sometimes hangs on 'Pending'.  Sometimes it gets further along on the 'Downloading' progress than others.  It downloads fine, very quickly, until it pauses.

Comment: Do you any external anti-virus/firewall/network security application turned on? Maybe that's what blocking the downloads.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy - None that I know of, but this isn't a clean install.  Good thought, ty...I'll have a look now.

Comment: Another thing I'd check is your region, either the real one you're in, or the one perceived by the OS - some apps are blocked in some regions.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy - No AV/security as far as I can tell.  There is space on the hard-drive.  I'm currently in Ireland and the region is set to Ireland. :(

Comment: Sorry @RobDude, sounds like you should call Microsoft support :(. You could launch into a troubleshooting session involving using FileMon, RegMon and/or ProcMon. But it could be a simple registry issue with your Windows license.

Comment: Run the WindowsUpdate troubleshooter: http://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-store-keep-pending-downloads-in-windows-8-1

Answer (score 0):

I tried pretty much every suggestion I could find on the internet, but nothing seemed to work.  I did a clean install and everything worked great / as expected.  Not much of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue too and stumbled upon the solution for me.

Somehow the store service was deactivated after an update. I don't know why or how, but I set it back to automatic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, another cause for this is if your OS install is not a clean install, if there's multiple copies of Windows on you HDD/SSD, or if your system partition is set to a non-standard drive path.  This should produce a unique error code somewhere though, I can't recall exactly but this occurred on one of my prior builds...